# Using WP Query, I want to include all posts in category 1 as long as they are not also in category 2

Tags: wp-query, categories, taxonomy

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => 'sorting_weight',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 81, // category 1, but for posts also in category 2 I want to exlcude
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: note that excluding things is very slow and very heavy on the database. You will need to cache this query if you intend to have more than a handful of concurrent visitors without full page caching, or lots of posts/terms. You should also avoid setting `posts_per_page` to `-1`, set it to a high number you never expect to reach but you know your server is capable of serving, otherwise the worst case scenario is your server falls over trying to load more posts than it has memory for or time to send. Also use `get_term_by` to grab the term ID, don't hardcode it

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try this type of code.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'meta_key'       => 'sorting_weight',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => 81, // category 1
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            'terms'    => 82, // category 2
        )
    )
);
```